# Product description is mixed in shortcodes

Tags: shortcode

Product description is mixed in shortcodes I am trying to remove the shortcode in the google feed description. Descpription is not looking very good.If anyone can help , I tried searching on google but its not helping.

I tried searching google and I couldnt find the possible solution. I need to strip the shortcodes from the description. in the google product feed.

[image]